# can't ssh passwordless - get another user

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, dsa

server 1 which dials into server 2

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024 (no password)
scp id_dsa.pub user@server2.com:/home/user/.ssh
```

server2:

```
[~/.ssh]# cat id_dsa.pub >> ./authorized_keys
```

But when I do ssh user@server2.com I get:

```
other-boxes-user@server2.com's password:
```

**EDIT:**

```
server1: ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024 (no password)
server1: ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa server2user@server2.com
server1: ssh server2user@server2.com -- get promoted for a password
```

How do I get the correct user used so I can login with no password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions on the `.ssh` directory and/or the files within it are wrong on the remote server.

You can fix these manually yourself, or just use the `ssh-copy-id` utility to copy your public keys over to the server. This will also fix any broken permissions of this type.

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa user@server2.com
```

If you still have trouble, you need to look at `sshd` debug logs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Where exactly are you adding the public key id_dsa.pub? Could it be you are appending it to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys instead of in /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys on server2? Make sure you place it in the authorized_keys of the respective user.

2 - permissions (as suggested by Michael)

```
chmod  700  /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

3 - server1: use the following command to connect.

```
  ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa user@server2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Below steps might help you

server 1
ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024 (no password)

scp id_dsa.pub user@server2.com:/home/user/.ssh

cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh user@remotehost 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'

chmod -R 700 /home/user/.ssh

chmod -R 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Server2

chmod -R 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys